# SQL server and trigger reflected changes order?

Tags: sql-server, triggers

Let's say I have a table and I set an  `after update` trigger which updates a column in the **same** changed row.

Does the trigger is promised to be executed immediately after the update but  before someone tries to read a value ?

Example :

there is a trigger for update , which sets `"IsNameSet"` to `1` ( when `name` is modified)

`update myTable set name="a"   where id={...}`

and then immediatly(!)

`select IsNameSet from myTable where id=...{modified row id}`

Does it guaranteed that i will always see `1` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `SELECT` happens before the `UPDATE` transaction (including the trigger) commits then it depends on the isolation level of the reading transaction.

At read uncommitted then it could read `name="a" and IsNameSet = 0`.

If snapshot it could read the pre-update value of the row. Otherwise it will be blocked reading the row until the `UPDATE` transaction commits and will read the "after" value.

Depending on the exact requirement this is possibly something a computed column could do more efficiently than a trigger.

Comment: So you're saying to set `IsNameSet` column as a computed column ? but doesn't it also depends on the Isolation level ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir - Just on the grounds of efficiency. Triggers have additional overhead as they need to populate the `INSERTED` and `DELETED` tables. But if you need to refer to the "before" value of the column then a computed column won't work.

Comment: what do you mean by " Just on the grounds of efficiency" ( sorry  , dont know what it means) . is it an answer for "_doesn't it also depends on the Isolation leve_" ?

Comment: @RoyiNamir If the computed column was persisted it would maybe be possible to come up with cases where `readuncommitted` would return inconsistent results for that as well. But the `SELECT` query shouldn't be using `readuncommitted` anyway if it wants transactionally consistent results.